# Python empty matches replaced

Tags: python, regex

I really don't understand the following example found on [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace):

`>>>> p = re.compile('x*')`

`>>>> p.sub('-', 'abxd')`

`'-a-b-d-'`

Why the regex `'x*'` is matching four times?

I thought the output should be: 'ab-'

Answer (score 3):

`*` meta character matches 0 or more times. So,

```
 a bx d
^ ^ -- ^
```

`^` is the position where `x*` matches 0 times and `--` is the place where `x*` matches 1 time. That is why the output is `-a-b-d-`.

To get the output `ab-d`, you need to use `x+` in the regular expression. It means that match one or more times. So, it will match only the following positions

```
abxd
  ^
```

Comment: Thank you @thefourtheye for you answer. An other question: in 'abxd' 'a' is the first character and 'd' is the last, so how is it possible that an empty match goes before the first position (before 'a') and after the last (after 'd')???

Comment: @Geekluca Think that an empty string is before and after all the strings :-)

Answer (score 0):

One update about re.sub since Python 3.7.

> Empty matches for the pattern are replaced when adjacent to a previous non-empty match.

The result becomes "-a-b--d-" because that "d" is now having an empty match. In the previous versions of python, this empty match is not allowed since it is adjacent to the matching of "x".